# Python curses: fetching data from API and getch() at the same time

Tags: python, curses

I'm pretty new to curses so sorry for a noob question :) I run `while True:` loop which fetches data from API and present them using function `show_header_and_footer()`. Then it sleeps for 3 seconds to avoid constant refreshing and exceeding the API-provider limit.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    setup_curses()

    while True:
        catch_input()
        show_header_and_footer()
        stdscr.refresh()
        header.refresh()
        footer.refresh()
        time.sleep(3)
```

As you probably noticed, there is also a call for `catch_input()` function which looks like that:

```
def catch_input():
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c in (ord('q'), ord('Q')): 
        curses.raw()
        curses.endwin()
```

Everything works, but after clicking 'Q' I have to wait until the end of `time.sleep(3)`. How can I improve that?

Answer (score 1):

**Note :** I assume that by pressing 'q'or'Q', you are exiting the application.

If that is true, why not return a status to the main from the catch_input() method. Use this status to return/break from the while(True) loop. This way you will not encounter the 3 second timer.

**catch_Input() method:**

```
def catch_input():
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c in (ord('q'), ord('Q')): 
        curses.raw()
        curses.endwin()
        return False
    return True
```

**Main method():**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

setup_curses()

while True:
    if not catch_input():
        break
    show_header_and_footer()
    stdscr.refresh()
    header.refresh()
    footer.refresh()
    time.sleep(3)
```